How to create a Linked Server to Oracle in SQL Server running in a container
I need to create a Linked Server from SQL Server to Oracle.
Both database servers must be running in a container.
I'm planning on using the following images:

mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest-lite

I have successfully started both database servers from a docker-compose file. When I connect to the SQL Server instance using SQL Server Management Studio, I cannot configure the Linked Server because there are no providers installed.
It seems I may have to create a custom Dockerfile for the SQL Server server to install the providers from there, but I cannot find any example on how to do this nor even what drivers/providers are needed.


As outlined in the comments by @AlwaysLearning, this is currently not
supported.


Non-SQL Server data sources are currently not supported on SQL Server for Linux editions (which includes Docker containers). Can you turn the connection requirement around and connect to SQL Server from Oracle?

@AlwaysLearning Unfortunately, I cannot. The main reason for having this setup is for running integration tests, where I'm running Oracle-specific queries (from MSSQL) through the OPENQUERY function.

Then you're need to not use a dockerised version of SQL Server, @GomalId .

@ThomA Looks like so.
